# How do I get the list of particpants linked to a photograph and their consent values?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I've inherited an Access database for a rugby club that was designed to allow them to catalogue photographs, who appears in the photo graphs and if the people in the photograph give their consent for it to be used in media publications.

I've not worked with any kind of SQL for a long **LONG** time so I'm feel a bit out of my depth here.

Here's what the database looks like:

[image: Database Relationship Diagram]

I'm sure that the SQL to pull out a record for a photo, listing the participants associated to it and their consent value should be trivial but everything I try fails.

Can anyone help shed some light on this for me? I'm feeling real dumb right about now.

Comment: what SQL have you tried so far, and what happened?

Comment: Seems to me that ConsentGiven should be in the participant table. Otherwise the same person has to give their consent for every picture (unless that is intentional). And I guess consent isn't needed for the opposing team players?

Comment: @SeanLange it's a SafeGuarding measure. They have to get consent for each picture that the participant is in. Participants aren't necessarily from the home team.

Comment: Makes sense. Not sure why the opposition team is listed in the photograph table but whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (untested):

```
SELECT
    [ph].[File Name], 
    [p].[Participant Name],
    [ptp].[Consent Given]
FROM
    [tblPhotograph] [ph]
    LEFT JOIN [tblParticipant_to_Photograph] [ptp] ON [ptp].[Photograph_ID] = [ph].[ID]
    LEFT JOIN [tblParticipant] [p] ON [p].[ID] = [ptp].[Participant_ID]
```

Comment: Looks like Martin beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

The following *untested* code will start you off in the correct direction for your query:

```
SELECT p.ID,
       pp.[Participant Name],
       ptp.[Consent Given]
  FROM tblPhotograph p
    LEFT JOIN tblParticipant_to_Photo ptp ON ptp.Photograph_ID = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN tblParticipant pp ON pp.ID = ptp.Participant_ID
```

Show the photograph id (`p.ID`), the name of the participant (`pp.[Participant Name]`), and whether consent is given (`ptp.[Consent Given]`) for each photograph.

The `tblPhotograph` table is joined to the `tblParticipant_to_Photo` table on the photograph's ID, and then joined to the `tblParticipant` on the participant's ID.

This will give you all results.  You may wish to reduce this to a single photograph, which you could do by adding a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE p.ID = 1
```

Changing `1` to the ID of the photograph you want.